# How to clone the homepage layout of Medium in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid

I am currently trying to create a medium clone using reactjs. I am now wondering as to how I would go about creating the "featured" section of the homepage.

I am planning to make use of a News API to fetch all my contents to which I am going to map out into their corresponding layouts. Thinking in react to the best of my ability, it is clear to me that both the vertical and horizontal layout of the contents in the "featured" section, needs their own separate component since one of them (horizontal component) gets reused in the "based on your reading" section. So, my question now is, how can I map the data fetched, into such layouts? Such a layout would be easy for me if I was to create each block of article manually using HTML, that way I can design (assign CSS class) each block separately, compared to designing blocks that get generated as the dom renders. Below is what I have done so far.

```
 useEffect(()=>{

        const fetch= async()=>{

            try{
                setLoading(true)
                const response= await axios(url)
                const results= response.data
                // console.log(results.articles.slice(0,5))
                setData(results.articles.slice(0,5))
                setLoading(false)
            }
            catch{
                setLoading(false)
            }  
        }
        fetch()

    },[url])


    const getData=(from,to)=>{
        const copiedData=[...data]
        const sliced= copiedData.slice(from,to)
        return sliced;
    }



return(
    <>
    <Categories onClick={fetchCategory}/>
    <section className={classes.featured}>
   //featured_vertical
    <Vertical postArray={getData(0,1)}  loading={isLoading}/>
    <div className={classes.featured_horizontals}>
        <Horizontal  postArray={getData(1,3)} />
    </div>
    <Vertical postArray={getData(3,4)}  loading={isLoading}/>
    </section>
    </>
)
}
```

I expected each slice to be passed into their components, but I ended up only managing to get the first vertical component to show.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--if you can create it in HTML then use that HTML in your component and pass in the data it needs to render as props. What specific issue is tripping you up?

Comment: This right here is my intention, but I seem to be unable to successfully splice the data fetched into the appropriate components.

Comment: What specific issue are you having with the data?

Comment: The getData function manages to get the fetched data stored in the state into only the first vertical component. I don't know if it's a state mutation problem or something.

Comment: Have you verified your getData function does what you think it does? And your original data? Etc: check your assumptions.

Comment: Thanks Dave for pointing that out! Funnily enough, I didn't run any test for my getData function. While I do that, do you have any other suggestion or the best practice to pass such data in this sort of context?

Comment: *shrug* The organization of data and components is kind of arbitrary.

Comment: _sigh_ I hear you Dave. I will keep on hacking! Thanks a lot.